# Trying to format string giving argument is not IFormatable

Tags: c#, string, format

Here is my code:

```
receipt.AmountCharged = String.Format("{0:C}", recordPaymentRequest.Payment);
```

I am getting a message at "0:C" saying:

> formatting is specified but argument is not IFormatable

If I try `.tostring("C")l` I get:

> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments
>   error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

How do I convert this to currency or 2 decimals?

And what does that iformatprovider mean?

For clarification:

```
[DataContract]
public class RecordPaymentRequest : TokenRequest {

    [DataMember]
    public string Payment {
        get { return payment; }
        set { payment = value; }
    }
```

Does that help?

Comment: What type is `recordPaymentRequest.Payment` ?

Comment: So it's already a string.  What's the format of the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Payment` property needs to be of a type that implements the `IFormatable` interface. In this case probably `Decimal` since Payment seems to be a money value.
If that is not possible you need to parse the string value first, for example:

```
receipt.AmountCharged = 
         String.Format("{0:C}", Decimal.Parse(recordPaymentRequest.Payment));
```